# What could be wrong here

Tags: mysql, create-table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'ci_sessions'; 
CREATE TABLE 'ci_sessions' (  
   'session_id' varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
   'ip_address' varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
   'user_agent' varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,  
   'last_activity' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
   'user_data' text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY ('session_id'),  
    KEY 'last_activity_idx' ('last_activity') ) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I've tried to run this code on phpMyAdmin and it says

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''ci_sessions'' at line 1

Comment: An inverted comma is not a backtick

Comment: so i need to replace all inverted coma in to back ticks?

Comment: Like I answered below, yes...

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between an identifier and a literal?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-identifier-and-a-literal)

Comment: or just remove them entirely.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same error in all your table and column names. You use `'` while you should use backticks:

```
`
```

So this should work:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ci_sessions`;
CREATE TABLE `ci_sessions` (
    `session_id` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ip_address` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `user_agent` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_activity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `user_data` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`) )
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

As a sidenote - you use NOT NULL and then set the default value to the string `0`. quite often. That indicates bad practice, or at least more work for later queries. A column named last_activity for example indicates that null values should be allowed...

Second sidenote - last_activity would typically be a DATETIME column, not an int(10)

Comment: A unixtimestamp would be a valid value for last_activity.

Comment: valid yes @Strawberry. But harder to query too